# Table nested by a factor variable - how to Sweave correctly?

Tags: r, sweave, xtable

I want to Sweave a table of matrices from an R script to a LaTeX document. I have results from which I need to pick some values to make up a matrix akin to this:

```
(for i in levels(groups)){

mat[[i]] <- matrix(item1[i],item2[i],
                   item3[i],item4[i],
                   nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=T)
dimnames(mat[[i]]) <- input.labels
}
```

Then I save this object mat as rda-file, read that in Rnw file and try to Sweave it in a LaTeX document with xtable. I want to have it so that there would be a table that has structure like this:

```
                      header1  header2
groups[1]   header1   item1[1] item2[1]
            header2   item3[1] item4[1]
groups[2]   header1   item1[2] item2[2]
            header2   item3[2] item4[2]
groups[3]   header1   item1[3] item2[3]
            header2   item3[3] item4[4]
```

all the way down to the last member of the groups factor. I have tried several ways to make this work but I haven't found a neat one yet. Does any one have suggestions?

Cheers,

Antti

Comment: Can you provide some example data so we can reproduce the situation? Can you specify which ways you have already tried?

Comment: This is one of the ways I tried:                                    <<gen-tables, results = tex>>=
d_ply(mat, .(groups), xtable, .print = TRUE)
@                                                                                                                                       It wouldn't give exactly same kind of table I'm after, but would convey all the information any way. The problem is that factor "groups" is not recognized by Sweave.